# How to allow other networks to connect to server nodejs socket io

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, vue.js, socket.io

I am attempting to create a live chat using socket.io, currently I can only connect if I am using my own network. (Testing through [ngrok]https://ngrok.com/).

How can I allow others to also connect?

socket.js file:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});


io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on('chat.message', function(message) {
    console.log(message)
     io.emit('chat.message', message)
  })
});
```

chat.js file:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('my_ipv4_address':3000');

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    mounted: function() {
      console.log('testing 123')
      socket.on('chat.message', function(message) {
        this.messages.push(message)
      }.bind(this));
    },
    data: {
      messages: [],
      message: null
    },
    methods: {
        send() {
            socket.emit('chat.message', this.message)
    }
}})
```

Comment: The question probably doesn't belong here since it's really about networking, not about code.  But, in a nutshell, you need to set up port forwarding on your router from a public port number to your private IP/port number.  Then, either connect to your router's public IP address directly from outside your network or set up a dynamic DNS name that points to your public IP address.  The router will then forward incoming connections to the host/port on  your private network.  Make absolutely sure your server is hardened against attack before doing so.

Comment: Thank you! I tested and it works. Can you suggest anything for security?

Answer (score 0):

@jfriend00 solved the issue.

I also changed

```
const socket = io('my_ipv4_address':3000');
```

to

```
const socket = io('my_public_ip':3000');
```